# Datagrid verticalLockedSeparatorSkin

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I want to change color and size of the vertical lock separator.
I try to that with Programating skin, but I didn't found how to change color.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Create a png and I define is as a Class.
[image]